# gspread "SpreadsheetNotFound" on certain workbooks

Tags: python, google-sheets, gspread

I have a google drive folder with hundreds of workbooks. I want to cycle through the list and update data. For some reason, gspread can only open certain workbooks but not others. I only recently had this problem.

It's not an access issue because everything is in the same folder.

I get `raise SpreadsheetNotFound` when I `open_by_key(key)`. But then when I take the key and paste it into an URL, the sheet opens. Which means it's not the key.

What's going on here? I'm surprised other people are not encountering this error.

Have I hit my limit on the number of Google sheets I can have? I have about 2 thousand.

Update: I find that if I go into the workbook and poke around, the sheet is then recognized??!! What does this mean? It doesn't recognize the sheet if the sheet isn't recently active???

Also if I try using Google App Script `SpreadsheetApp.openById`, the key is recognized! So the sheet is there, I just can't open it with `gspread`. I have use Google script to write something to the sheet first before it is recognized by `gspread`.

I'm able to open the sheet using `pygsheets` but since it is new and so buggy, i can't use it. It looks like a `APIv4` issue? Some sheets can't be opened with `APIv3`?

update: here is another observation. Once you open the workbook with APIv4, you can no longer open it with V3.

Comment: maybe individual workbooks in the folder are not shared with the google service account client?

Comment: @ Haleemur Ali. No the whole folder is shared with the client

Comment: Just an idea: have you tried `open_by_url` instead of `open_by_key`?

Comment: You can also try to reproduce the problem on `google-api-python-client` (it's a v4 api client that seem to be recommended instead of `gspread`).

Comment: Good suggestion, but `open_by_url` also gives me the same error. I pasted the exact url of the browser into the code.

Comment: Facing the same issue, please help!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54793652/gspread-exception-spreadsheet-not-found-on-a-particular-sheet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like you are hitting a limitation in `gspread`.

Even if you open a spreadsheet by key, `gspread` still first downloads a feed of all explicitely shared sheets using `https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full` and checks if the key you have provided is among them.

The problem is that this feed only lists 500 files. If your key is not among these 500, then you'll get `SpreadsheetNotFound` even if the spreadsheet is accessible.

I'd guess that the feed is ordered by most recently used, that explains why editing it makes it visible to `gspread` again.

The relevant issue is [here](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/issues/233).

Answer (score 4):

I've run into this issue repeatedly. The only consistent fix I've found is to "re-share" the file with the api user. It already lists the api user as shared (since it's in the same shared folder as everything else), but after "re-sharing" I can connect with gspread no problem.

Based on this I believe it may actually be a permissions issue (Google failing to register the correct permission for the API user when accessing it through APIv3).

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that you may be hitting the `Google Drive API`  limit of *"Queries per 100 seconds per user"*, which is `1000` and cannot be changed to a higher value.

**Solution 1:**

You can try to apply for a higher quota by going to you **project page**:
1 -  **DASHBOARD**
2 - **QUOTAS**
3 - Click on the pencil after "***Queries per 100 seconds per user***"
4 - Then click "***Apply for higher quota***"
5 - You'll end-up on https://support.google.com/code/contact/drive_quota, but if you follow steps above, the form will have the `project` and `user` details already filled.

---

**Solution 2:**

I had the same issue with just a couple of spreadsheets on my account, the problem was solved by:

1 - Opening the json key file (`projectname-ca997255dada.json`)
2 - Find the value of `client_email` , i.e.:

```
"client_email": "278348728734832-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
```

3 - Share your sheet(s) with that email

**Note:** You can try to change just one spreadsheet that you cannot open and check if the above solve the problem.

Comment: I don't think that is right, because I would wake up first thing in the morning and try to run a simple code to open just one sheet. Basically the first request of the day... and that still doesn't work.

Comment: Have you considered firewal or AV interference ?

Comment: Yeah, that's not the issue.

Comment: I don't think it's even _possible_ to hit that API rate (at least with gspread). The API is too slow that you could be opening sheets in 0.1 sec. The answer by [dorian](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43388669/4799172) makes the most sense to me, especially in the light of opening the file manually suddenly causing it to be found.