# gspread.exception Spreadsheet not Found on a particular sheet

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-drive-realtime-api, gspread

I am working to get google sheets downloaded on my EC2 linux server.I shared the google sheet with email id from credentials json file. I am using gspread, to open the sheet using open_by_key(file['id']) and the code works when I run using root but not using a different user having the same properties. It gives this error :
       File "/home/edh/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gspread/client.py", 
       line 113, in open_by_key
       raise SpreadsheetNotFound
       gspread.exceptions.SpreadsheetNotFound

This code works in team drives too. The weird thing is I am able to run this code over different google sheets in the same user of EC2, but this particular sheet gives the above error. 
Please help and let me know if you need any more info from my side.

Comment: Is this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42382847/gspread-spreadsheetnotfound-on-certain-workbooks) relevant to your issue?

Comment: That issue is not working for me since I tried all of the solutions mentioned there :(

Comment: @PrajaktaYerpude, were you able to resolve this?